# What is the difference of "redis client list" with "connected client from info"

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am checking the actually connected clients from Redis. Which one should tell me the truth? I know "redis-cli client list" can give me more info.

However, The total sum of this is different from the value in connected clients in (redis-cli info). How can I understand the difference between these two? Who should I trust for the amount of the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken directly from the Redis Docs, [here](https://redis.io/commands/client-list) and [here](https://redis.io/commands/info), these are the differences:

> The CLIENT LIST command returns information and statistics about the
>   client connections server in a mostly human readable format.

And...

> The INFO command returns information and statistics about the server
>   in a format that is simple to parse by computers and easy to read by
>   humans.

However, to answer your question, both commands should tell you the same number of connections unless the connection is a replica as stated in the docs for the `INFO` command...

> connected_clients: Number of client connections (excluding connections
>   from replicas)

`CLIENT LIST` is what you should be relying on for key data about your clients/connections

Comment: Thanks. But the thing is we are not seeing client_list summary amout is equal to total connected_clients. That is the problem. Which one is the truth. what is the difference of these two underlying in Redis?

Comment: @JamesXu So when you count the clients in `CLIENT INFO` and subtract those that are replicas or slaves, the number you see is different than `connected_clients` in `INFO clients`?